# Can Mac/Apple read .bmp?

Tags: xml, xcode

Can the .bmp photograph format be used by Mac/Apple computers?

BACKGROUND: We have a family project to create a Mac/Apple picture book. I copied pictures for it scanned into my PC using the .bmp option. I then downloaded the images to a disc to send snail mail to the picture book organizer who uses only a Mac/Apple computer. Now the Mac/Apple user is concerned that my pictures can't be downloaded properly into their computer.  I have been asked to redo the project in .jpg.

Comment: Almost all image formats are interchangeable between Windows / OSX. BMP, JPG, PNG, etc...

Comment: Ouch! Don't use BMP for photos. BMP can be converted to JPEG, but don't use BMP for photos.

Comment: To expand on the comment by mspasov, the reason one would prefer JPEG to BMP is that BMP has little data compression, so the file size will be much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Check out following link for supported image types on both mac and windows, mac almost support most of the image type.

http://www.cnsplug-ins.com/Plug-ins/CNS_Image/Knowledge_Base/Documentation/Supported_Image_Types